# checking for duplicates in panda data frame

Tags: pandas, plot, duplicates

```
import pandas as pd
from io import StringIO
import requests
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
from scipy.interpolate import make_interp_spline
url = 'https://m-selig.ae.illinois.edu/ads/coord/b737a.dat'
response = requests.get(url).text

lines = []
for idx, line in enumerate(response.split('\n'), start=1):
    if all([x.replace('.','').replace('-','').isdecimal() for x in line.split()]):
        lines.append(line)

lines = [x.split() for x in lines]
df = pd.DataFrame(lines)
df = df.dropna(axis=0)
df = df.astype(float)
df = df[~(df > 1).any(1)]
print(df)
```

output...

```
         0       1
2   0.0000  0.0177
3   0.0023  0.0309
4   0.0050  0.0372
5   0.0076  0.0415
6   0.0143  0.0499
7   0.0249  0.0582
8   0.0495  0.0730
9   0.0740  0.0814
10  0.0990  0.0866
11  0.1530  0.0907
12  0.1961  0.0905
13  0.2504  0.0887
14  0.3094  0.0858
15  0.3520  0.0833
16  0.3919  0.0804
17  0.4477  0.0756
18  0.5034  0.0696
19  0.5593  0.0626
20  0.5965  0.0575
21  0.6488  0.0498
22  0.8351  0.0224
23  0.9109  0.0132
24  1.0000  0.0003
26  0.0000  0.0177
27  0.0022  0.0038
28  0.0049 -0.0018
29  0.0072 -0.0053
30  0.0119 -0.0106
31  0.0243 -0.0204
32  0.0486 -0.0342
33  0.0716 -0.0457
34  0.0979 -0.0516
35  0.1488 -0.0607
36  0.1953 -0.0632
37  0.2501 -0.0632
38  0.2945 -0.0626
39  0.3579 -0.0610
40  0.3965 -0.0595
41  0.4543 -0.0563
42  0.5050 -0.0527
43  0.5556 -0.0482
44  0.6063 -0.0427
45  0.6485 -0.0375
46  0.8317 -0.0149
47  0.9410 -0.0053
48  1.0000 -0.0003
```

This is my code for a website I'm scraping data from. I'm running into a problem where the x points start from zero, go up, and come back down to zero creating a line in the middle of the plot which I don't need.
Notice how there is two `df[0] = 0`  on rows 2 and 26, How can I write a code where it detects duplicates?

Answer (score 0):

Try one of the following?

Out of the loop

```
df1=df.drop_duplicates(keep='first', inplace=False, ignore_index=False)
```

Inside your loop

```
lines = []
lines1 = []
for idx, line in enumerate(response.split('\n'), start=1):
if all([x.replace('.','').replace('-','').isdecimal() for x in line.split()]):
        if  not (line in lines1): lines.append(line)
        lines1.append(line)
```